# Why in Guava filter/transform functions sometimes return modifiable view and some returns unmodifiable view?

Tags: java, guava

For example all Lists, Collections2, Sets return a modifiable view - removing from view collection will remove original items.

This works fine:

```
List<Integer> list = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -1, -2, -3, -4);    
Collection<Integer> transform = Collections2.filter(
    list, new Predicate<Integer>() {
        public boolean apply(Integer input) {
            return input.intValue() > 0;
        }
    });
transform.clear();
```

When I use Iterables and Iterators methods filter/transform I get umodifiable view (i.e all this code reuse UnmodifibleIterator).

This doesn't work:

```
List<Integer> list = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -1, -2, -3, -4);
Iterable<Integer> transform = Iterables.filter(
    list, new Predicate<Integer>() {
        public boolean apply(Integer input) {
            return input.intValue() > 0;
        }
    });
Iterables.removeIf(transform, Predicates.<Object>alwaysTrue());
```

I can't find any semantic difference between Iterable and Collection/List/Set/Map so why there are so different implementations in Guava?

The other strange behavior is that the iterator in the first case still doesn't allow the remove operation, but clear or remove/removeAll works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Iterators.transform` (and `Iterables.transform`, by extension) does support `remove()`. From its Javadoc:

> The returned iterator supports `remove()` if the provided iterator does.

`Iterators.filter`, however, does not. The reason for this is that there is no way for a filtered iterator to implement `hasNext()` without calling `next()` on the underlying iterator. Calling `hasNext()` on the underlying iterator is not enough, because the next element in that iterator (and every one after that as well, possibly) may not match the `Predicate`.

The problem, then, is that calling `hasNext()` on the filtered iterator *must* advance the position of the underlying iterator. This prevents a subsequent call to `remove()` from removing the element that was returned by the most recent call to `next()` (which is part of the contract of `remove()`). Thus, `remove()` cannot be supported on a filtered iterator.

The `Iterator` for a filtered `Collection` has the exact same issue (in fact, it's created using `Iterators.filter`). The `clear()` and `removeAll` methods work because they have full control over the iterator (they are both implemented using `Iterables.removeIf`).

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. Pity that sometimes it just impossible to makes thinks correct.

Comment: By the way such iterator can throw exception only in case of called hasNext() before using current value and in common(most popular) case such as `while(i.hasNext()){i.next(); i.remove();}` it dosn't reuired. So it was possible to make it works for almost all cases and only in some unregular ones throw such excpetion....